# What word means people who blindly follow the routine?

Tags: single-word-requests

What’s the word for people who act mindlessly,  accepting and  following the routine they have been told to follow by either society or government or something?

Comment: This isn't quite the word you're looking for, but if you're looking for someone who is deliberately obtrusive by following their instructions to the letter, you're looking for a jobsworth: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jobsworth

Comment: @Gaurav I really like Jobsworth and really needed this word right now, thank you.  I clicked the question thinking I'd find something close enough to what I was looking for and in your comment found the perfect word. :D

Comment: I think a very suitable word is **apparatchik**, a loan-word from Russian that has as its figurative meaning (according to _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_) "a blindly devoted official, follower, or member of an organization (as a corporation or political party).""

Comment: Related: [Can anything be done about mean-spirited requests for terminology?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4842)

Answer (score 43):

[image]

---

Though such specimens are actually members of the genus *Homo* and the species *domesticus*, this ubiquitous biped is often referred to, figuratively and derogatively, as a ***sheep*** (to the consternation of many even-toed ungulates). Note: political activists, ironically, refer to such as *citizens*. ;-)

---

[**The race of man, while sheep in credulity, are wolves for conformity**.](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/keywords/sheep_2.html)–--Carl Clinton Van Doren

[**We need more people speaking out. This country is not overrun with rebels and free thinkers. It's overrun with sheep and conformists**.](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/keywords/sheep_2.html)---Bill Maher

[**What do you get for pretending the danger's not real! Meek and obedient you follow the leader... into the valley of steel**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqlsVZ1zxMk)---Pink Floyd

---

> [**sheep**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sheep) *noun, often attributive*:
>
> 1: any of various hollow-horned typically gregarious ruminant mammals (genus Ovis) related to the goats but stockier and lacking a beard in the male; specifically:  **one** (*O. aries*) **long domesticated especially for its flesh** and wool**
>
> 2a: **a timid defenseless creature**
>
> 2b: **a timid docile person; especially:  one easily influenced or led** (Merriam-Webster *online*)

---

**Etymology**

---

> [**sheep**](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=sheep&allowed_in_frame=0) (*noun*) ruminant mammal, Old English *sceap*, *scep*, from West Germanic *skæpan* (cognates: Old Saxon *scap*, Old Frisian *skep*, Middle Low German *schap*, Middle Dutch *scaep*, Dutch *schaap*, Old High German *scaf*, German *Schaf*), of unknown origin. Not found in Scandinavian (Danish has *faar* for "sheep") or Gothic (which uses lamb), and with no known cognates outside Germanic. The more usual Indo-European word for the animal is represented in English by ewe.
>
> The plural form was leveled with the singular in Old English, but Old Northumbrian had a plural *scipo*. **Used since Old English as a type of timidity** and figuratively of those under the guidance of God. **The meaning "stupid, timid person" is attested from 1540s**. The image of the wolf in sheep's clothing was in Old English (from Matt. vii:15); that of separating the sheep from the goats is from Matt. xxv:33. To count sheep in a bid to induce sleep is recorded from 1854 but seems not to have been commonly written about until 1870s. It might simply be a type of a tedious activity, but an account of shepherd life from Australia from 1849 ["*Sidney's Emigrant's Journal*"] describes the night-shepherd ("hut-keeper") taking a count of the sheep regularly at the end of his shift to protect against being answerable for any animals later lost or killed.
>
> Sheep's eyes "loving looks" is attested from 1520s (compare West Frisian *skiepseach*, Dutch *schaapsoog*, German *Schafsauge*). A sheep-biter was "a dog that worries sheep" (1540s); "a mutton-monger" (1590s); and "a whore-monger" (1610s, i.e. one who "chases mutton"); hence Shakespeare's *sheep-biting* "thieving, sneaky."

---

(etymonline)

Answer (score 28):

> [**automaton**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/automaton) *noun*:
>
> 1: a mechanism that is relatively self-operating
>
> 2: a machine or control mechanism designed to follow automatically a predetermined sequence of operations or respond to encoded instructions
>
> 3: **an individual who acts in a mechanical fashion**
> (Merriam-Webster *online*)

Comment: @LittleEva:  Thank you.  Imitation is the sincerest form of flattery, right?  I'm new here and thought your format looked nice!

Comment: And, welcome to the site, it's a great place. BTW, if you haven't done so already, click on *help* and visit the Help center & Meta, both will enhance your EL&U experience. :-)

Comment: Figuratively, this is a good answer. I wanted to include this in my own, when describing mechanical, with a reference to the [mindless automation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=mindless+automaton) card from Magic the Gathering but you beat me to the punch, so to speak. This is worthy of my vote.

Answer (score 15):

[Drone](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=drone&defid=4040961):

> a mindless worker/sales person at stores. Generally refers to an employee of a large company, ideally a grocery store.

Answer (score 11):

I'm sure there are many words that apply but the first one that springs to my mind is this one:

---

> [Conformist](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=conformist&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on) , n. One who conforms or complies; appropriately, one who complies with the worship of the church of England or of the established church, as distinguished from a dissenter, or nonconformist.

---

Do not mind the religious association, since many English words have those and Webster's dictionary simply tends to just make them more obvious. For reference, in this particular context [conform](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=conform&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on) means:

---

> 1. To comply with or yield to; to live or act according to; as, to conform to the fashion or to custom.
> 2. To comply with; to obey; as, to conform to the laws of the state.

---

I am hesitant to suggest it since, in its proper form, calling a person a "conformist" does not tell us much more than that a person is [conformant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conformance) (dictionary.com) and in Webster's words, appropriate is virtually the opposite signification of mindless. In a purely lexical sense, somebody may have good reasons for their [conformity](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=conformity&use1828=on), which can make the orders, customs, creeds, traditions or laws very [conformable](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=conformable&use1828=on), in the specific sense of their agreeableness. Conform can also mean to make alike generally but especially in terms shape.

However, considering most members of any society or group are conformist to at least some degree and the mere mention of a word implies a reason for it. In more recent and critical times, the most usual one is that the conformity referred to is in lack of a good reason or even despite deleterious effects. Indeed, [according to *The Free Dictionary by Farlex*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conformist), the fifth edition of the *American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language* describes conformists as being "habitual" or "uncritical" (as well as dropping the religious connotation). [On the same page](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conformist), the 2010 edition of the *Random House Kernerman Webster’s College Dictionary* adds "unquestioningly" to the list of categorically thoughtless traits a conformist may exhibit. You will sometimes hear a phrase like "Don't be such a conformist!", when somebody wants you to do something unusual, especially if it is troublesome.

---

With varying degrees of accuracy, might also call such a person a slave:

---

> 1. A person who is wholly subject to the will of another; one who has no will of his own, but whose person and services are wholly under the control of another.

---

In [Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary](http://biblehub.com/dictionary/web.htm), 1913 the adjective [slavish](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=Slavish&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on) is also applicable:

---

> a. Of or pertaining to slaves; such as becomes or befits a slave; servile; excessively laborious; as, a slavish life; a slavish dependance on the great. -- Slav"ish*ly, adv. -- Slav"ish*ness, n.

---

Usually the emphasis upon this word regards the degree of control and obligation, most often under duress, to perform services. Still, it is used this way in a more figurative sense. George Washington famously used this word in his [General Orders of July 2 1776](http://www.thirty-thousand.org/pages/Free_Men.htm) to describe how he wanted the American army to differ from the British one, like this:

---

> “Let us, therefore, animate and encourage each other, and shew the whole world that a free man, contending for liberty on his own ground, is superior to any slavish mercenary on earth."

---

If there is anybody who ever lived that knows quite what a slave is like, except maybe a slave, it would likely be George Washington. He had over 300 of them at his estate on Mount Vernon, mostly inherited, [which he freed in his last will and testament.](http://gwpapers.virginia.edu/history/articles/freeing-his-slaves/) It should be noted that he was no hypocrite in this this matter, [since he allegedly argued against the use of African-American slaves in the war effort in his General Orders of Dec. 30th 1775](http://gwpapers.virginia.edu/history/articles/species/), publicly because he knew their performance would have been lacking but also privately because of the pangs of his guilty conscious, which is another subject altogether.

---

There are various figurative ways of describing such a person as well as I'm sure the others will and have been demonstrating.

The one I like most, at least for now, is "Mechanical" describing somebody as being like a machine machine. Machines as we know them today are automatic; presumably unfeeling; indifferent to the purpose of their operations and often, albeit not always, feel very cold due to the highly conductive metals often used in their construction. That potential coldness plays nicely into emotional coldness. I am somewhat surprised that more dictionaries do not reference this meaning, since it is a common analogy, although *Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged* (1991-2003) does on [as shown by The Free Dictionary by Farlex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/number+one).

---

Except where otherwise noted, all referenced definitions are from [Noah Webster's 1828 American Dictionary of the English Language](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/).

Comment: I disagree.  Conformist is not the word to use.  It has nothing to do with mindless.  The word is TOTALLY wrong.

Comment: @user116032 I just edited my post a little in response and I do agree, given the primary definition I directly quoted. Feel free to vote against my answer based upon that. However if uncritical and habitual from the American Heritage Dictionary  definition I already had up beforehand, aren't mindless traits, what are? By the way, do you have opinions on the other words I suggested? Also, so long as I'm writing this I would like to thank Little Eva for the compliment.

Comment: Yes Tonepoet, I also appreciate your labor in formatting, citations, links ... makes it very convenient for users to follow and check upon your assertions, information and reasoning. This type of thorough, stand-alone answer will always receive positive votes as long as its assertion(s) is within the realm of plausiblity.

Answer (score 8):

**Sheeple**

Which is a concatenation of "people" and "sheep" and ascribes to the people the archetypal behaviour of the sheep, which is to blindly follow what the rest of the flock is doing.

Edit: Definition by me.

Comment: Also note that Google is not considered a source. Google is just a directory of links to sources, but not a source in itself, and search results differ between users and nations (what you see may be different from what I see). The dictionary definitions that pop up on Google are notoriously hard to track down, too, as they don't tell you what dictionary they come from. As such, you should always use real dictionaries (The Free Dictionary is a good place to start, as it contains definitions—with links—to several different online dictionaries), and then link straight to them. :-)

Comment: Can you cite an authoritative example of usage of 'Sheeple'?

Answer (score 4):

> [**Zombie**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/zombie): a person whose behavior or responses are wooden, listless, or seemingly rote; automaton.

Answer (score 4):

Nobody has suggested "robot". That's an appropriate word.

Comment: Hey, while I on one hand appreciate the grammar checks I'd like to turn on the button that says: "Let her embarrass herself."  Editing a comments seems ... well... it just seems.  Please don't do it.  Nuke it or leave it alone.  With all respect. I'm more comfortable with the delete than with the edit.  - Wilson Smith

Comment: Nope, in these sites, in order to ensure an highest quality as possible, users are **expected** to edit each other's posts when they find some mistake or typos – as long as they don't change the meaning, of course.

Comment: I'd prefer *robotic*. Also, how about a dictionary reference and definition to improve the answer?

Answer (score 3):

**indoctrinated** (*adj.*), derived from **indoctrinate** (*verb*):

teach (a person or group) to accept a set of beliefs uncritically

> *'broadcasting was a vehicle for indoctrinating the masses'*

Source: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)

Further information on **indoctrination** (*noun*) is available at: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indoctrination)

Answer (score 1):

Some refer to such people as *cattle*. Like many domesticated livestock, dairy and beef cattle are generally docile and complacent.

I prefer *cattle* in particular (vs. *sheep*, for example) because cows are also used in metaphor to describe laziness, fatness, and slowness, being very complacent to stand or slowly walk around a small enclosure or pasture, chewing and regurgitating grass for their entire lives.

Cattle are also often corraled, i.e. guided by cattle farmers through mazeworks for purposes of organization and processing (e.g. for administration of medication, medical examination, horn removal, tagging/branding, etc.).

Finally, and most poignantly, cattle are often raised to be slaughtered and consumed. Their whole environment, from the pasture to the corral to their stall at the slaughterhouse, is designed to not only lull the cow into complacency but also to fatten them so they yield more profit for the farmer. Too similarly, people who are complacent with a repetitive routine in the doldrums are being farmed by their employers and even to some extent society in general, their complacency assuring consistent production of profit often at the expense of the person's very health and longevity.

From the time they grow up at school (the pasture) to the career-building process (the corral) to the cubicle (the stall at the slaughterhouse), the whole lifestyle of those hanging on a rung of the corporate ladder is a bit too easy to parallelize to that of cud-munching moobags (cows).

Answer (score 0):

> [**jobsworth**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/jobsworth): an official who upholds petty rules even at the expense of humanity or common sense.

Answer (score -1):

One word is "Methodist" and another is " Traditionalist " as in one who blindly follows Denominational Traditions in the realm of religion.

Comment: This is rather offensive to traditionalists who have carefully considered their position, isn't it?